# Hyper-V SERVER R2 Cluster

Tags: hyper-v

I keep hearing and reading that Hyper-V Server 2008 R2 can be clustered, but I can't find out how to set this up.

I can find how to cluster Windows Server 2008 R2 with Hyper-V.  I understand how to do this, bBut "How do you set up Hyper-V SERVER 2008 R2 in a cluster"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

[Here's](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=CD828712-8D1E-45D1-A290-7EDADF1E4E9C&displaylang=en) Microsoft's "Step-by-Step Guide for Testing Hyper-V and Failover Clustering" document, hopefully it'll answer your question.

Comment: It's worth noting that clustering isn't for the faint of heart, it's expensive and complicated. Here's another (more brief) MS walk-through on Hyper-V Failover Clustering: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732181(WS.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

That's for 2008 Server, I believe - here's an updated 2008 R2 Cluster guide: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755009.aspx

Another post with another link - make sure you read this, along with all linked docs: http://blogs.msdn.com/clustering/archive/2009/02/19/9433146.aspx

Comment: The processes is essentially the same in both 2008 and R2. There's just more benefits with R2.

Comment: Are you sure? I don't recall the Cluster evaluator in 2008...